# require is not loading modules properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

fter including require tag the application is behaving abnormal way .is there any way i can bootstrap my application apart from below code .

```
main.js 

require(['/module.js'], function() {
            angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
            });     
});
```

When I written as single file js file the code is working properly.

```
module.js

var name = 'myApp';
angular.module(name, [])
   .controller('Controller', require(['controller.js']))
   .factory('Service', require(['service.js']))
   .filter('Number', require(['filter.js']));
```

I have included my main.js in index.html . index html has 3 views i am displaying them based on ng-show from index.html.

The problem is module.js loading properly and js files too. Script is not executing properly so that my entire index.html page including 3 views displayed automatically with error messages.

Control is not going to controller.js/service.js

```
Error :
Error: Unknown provider: depsProvider <- deps .
```

Did i miss any define code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Angular does not support AMD by default, You need to config angular to export angular object. Please check out the this [post](https://www.startersquad.com/blog/angularjs-requirejs/) for more details.

```
require.config({

    paths: {
        'angular': '../lib/angular/angular'
    },

    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    }
});
```

Your module.js should be defined with define method of requirejs and it should return module.

You can omit file extesion (.js) while using requireJs

Comment: Can i write without using domReady --I dont want to use domReady.How do i bootstrap app . require(['domReady!'], function (document) {
        ng.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });

Comment: use angular.element(document).ready to detect dom ready event